# Chrome extension options

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-options

In the manifest.json of my extension, I added this:

```
  "options_ui": {
      "page": "options.html",
      "chrome_style": true
  },
```

My options page (options.html) has this right before the closing body tag:

```
<script src="options.js"></script>
```

Both options.html and options.js are in the same folder.
options.js starts with this:

```
console.log('options.js');
```

Problem: I am loading the unpacked extension (developer mode enabled). My options page is showing fine, but the script is not loaded. I have defined event handlers in that file, and they do nothing.
options.js is not executed.

I followed all the instructions [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2), but it just does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>the new "chrome_style" options actually don't show anything logged to the console trough `console.log`, your script is probably fine, try adding something to the dom.</s>

Add this at the beginning of your script to see any errors happening in your chrome options page:

```
var errorText = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(errorText)
window.onerror = function (msg, file, line, column) {
  errorText.innerHTML = msg + '<br>' + file + ' ' + line + ':' + column;
}
```

EDIT:
Right click inside the Options UI, select "Inspect element", it will open the appropriate debugger.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I did what you told me and see it is loaded. So now I need to find out why the event handlers are not working...

Comment: Yes options page development is tricky as you can't debug the code ether, see my updated answer for a script you can use.

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful. I found out that there was a 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined' error. I had to set the storage permission for the extension.

Comment: I don't think your first paragraph is correct.  It appears you can right click to bring up the appropriate console.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the new options_ui does log things to the console, just not the console you’re looking at with “View” “Javascript Console”.  Instead, right click on the option page that opens, and “Inspect Element”.  That will bring up the correct “Developer Menu”.